# Capturing removeObject from indexedDB

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, addeventlistener, indexeddb

Using a cursor I'm displaying all objects in my indexedDB. My assignment requires us to have an admin account be created on page launch. I've used a localStorage API to  record that the account has been created as to not continuously create this admin account. When a new user is created and displayed, there's a remove button added next to their name.

**I'm trying to launch a function that would change the localStorage of the admin key: function adminRemoved(), if the admin account were to be removed. But I don't know how's I'd be able to capture that event.**

This is the function to show the list of all users in the DB:

```
function showUserList(e){
    //var result = e.target.result;
    //databox.innerHTML = '<div>' + result.id + ' - ' + result.name + ' - ' + result.date + '</div>';
    var cursor = e.target.result; // Capture multiple return values as a cursor
    // Modify the databox to show the results 
    if (cursor){        
        databox.innerHTML += '<div>' + 
        cursor.value.userName + ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.fn+ ' - ' + 
        cursor.value.ln+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.pw+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.em+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.dob+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.tel+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.bio+ ' - '+ 
        cursor.value.tm+ ' - '+
        cursor.value.scl+' - '+
        cursor.value.gender+ 
        ' <input type="button" onclick="removeobject(\'' + cursor.value.userName + '\')" value="remove"/></div>';
            // Add a remove button as inserted HTML
        cursor.continue(); // Iterates over the cursor
    }
}
```

I want to run this function when the admin account is removed:

```
function adminRemoved(){
    var admin ='admin';
    var status = 'removed';
    newItem(admin,status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The names of your functions don't correspond. In the onclick it is called "removeobject" and the function name is "adminRemoved". Name them the same and maybe put "javascript:" before the function in the onclick event of your button. This should work.

Maybe easier to do this is by using some lib like jQuery to create the controls. It will be easier to attach events.